# How to calculate textbox value in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i am using a containplaceholder in contain page.

there apply

I want to calulate two textbox value and result show in another textbox by javascript.

so please help me ,how to doing this job.(asp.net)

Answer (score 0):

see this example its help you

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/17/10194406/adding-two-textbox-values-and-showing-in-third-textbox-on-clientside.aspx